# login: admin is simply ignored

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have this app.yaml:

```
application: xyz
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /admin/.*
  script: admin.app
  login: admin

- url: /.*
  script: main.app


libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

when I access /admin/, both the dev server and appengine display the contents without asking for authentication. What gives?

Comment: Besides the extra ` character at the end of the file you pasted everything seems okay. Did you try clearing your cookies/browser cache?

Comment: That was a typo as I was entering this, it's not in the actual config. The cookies were it. They were like 3 months old though.

Comment: Cool, I'll add that as an answer so this can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this before. Try clearing your cookies. Clearing the cookies also helps if you accidentally forgot to check "log in as administrator" when the dev server prompts you for the fake login info.